# Randomization of words in PHP

Tags: php, random

I'm trying to code a small emailing script and I am wondering how I can add text in a format like {Hello|Hi|Hey|Hola} in my text only email template and every time one word would randomly be used in the email.

Can someone give me any hint on how I can do that?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do some of your own research first. This appears to be a relatively simple problem to solve. Try writing your own code first, then if you are having trouble, post your code and the specific problem you are having and we can try and help you.

Comment: I would start here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_rand.asp

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 1):

```
 $TextToRandomise = ['Hello', 'Hi', 'Hey', 'Hola'];
 $HelloText       = $TextToRandomise[rand(0,3)];
```

you should look on google before asking questions here, because this is easy code.

```
 $str       = "Hello|Hi|Hey|Hola";
 $array     = explode('|', $str);
 $HelloText = $array[rand(0,3)];
```

Comment: _you should look on google before asking questions here, because this is easy code._ Agreed! Why do you answer then an off-topic question?

Comment: As a beginner we do not have all the good reflexes. I just give him a little clue and guide him to google.anyway my solution does not allow him to write all his email 'engine'.

Comment: Thank you for giving me an idea of what I should look for, appreciate it very much!

Comment: if you want to replace / take away the "{" and "}"  you may look at str_replace function https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp      or with regex https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: And if you want to match the perfect string {Hello|Hi|Hey|Hola}  as an array you should look at preg_match, regex work really good for this. https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php